# Be careful climbing that tree. You (can / could) fall

Tags: modal-verbs, can-modal

> Be careful climbing that tree. You (can / could) fall.

The answer is "could".

I would choose "could" if I had to, but I can't seem to explain why "can" doesn't work here.

Comment: "Can" *can* work here.

Comment: _Can_ is more often used of things a person might want to do rather than a risk they run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both "can" and "could" can be used here, but "could" sounds better.

"Can" *usually* means the ability of someone to do something, but in this case it uses the other meaning of "possibility of something happening", so "could" would be slightly better

As what @KateBunting has said, "Can" is more often used of things a person might want to do rather than a risk they run, so if you had the choice in this case, pick "could", as in this context the person is probably getting something (maybe not running up the tree for fun).

Not only does it sound better using "could", if you say "you can fall" to someone, sounds as though you think they might want to!

Comment: There's no context provided here. So I wonder why you--and apparently the author of this test question--would presume that "you are quite unsure whether you would fall off the tree". For example, the speaker might know something about that tree and have a reason to believe that you would fall if you climbed it.

Comment: my bad @listeneva ill change my answer

Comment: @listeneva issit better now?

Comment: Yes, but the test question doesn't seem to agree with you. They say you need _could_, not _can_. https://english-practice.net/english-grammar-exercises-could-do-and-could-have-done/

Comment: I mean, both can be used, "could" is definitely clearer and better, but in tests, you can only have 1 correct option, so choose the better one! :) @listeneva

Comment: The test question is not "choose the better answer", but something like "choose the required answer"

Comment: Andy Bonner also stated that "can" can be used as well as "could" @listeneva

Comment: I have added Kate Bunting's comment into my ans pls check it again, use "could" as not only is it better, it flows with the sentence better!

Comment: @DialFrost - I think you misunderstood my comment. I wasn't talking about the reason for climbing the tree. We say things like "You can see for miles from the top of this hill", "You can get a cup of tea here if you want one". Saying "You can fall from the tree" sounds as though you think they might want to!

Comment: ah that was my own adding in @KateBunting

Comment: @KateBunting But "accidents can happen" sounds more idiomatic than "accidents could happen".

Comment: True - see [this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=accidents+can+happen%2C+accidents+may+happen%2C+accidents+could+happen&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caccidents%20can%20happen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caccidents%20may%20happen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caccidents%20could%20happen%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Caccidents%20can%20happen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caccidents%20may%20happen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caccidents%20could%20happen%3B%2Cc0) - but we are more likely to use _could_ or _might_ when referring to the likelihood of a particular accident.